# How to insert many data to database with php

Tags: php, mysql, post

I tried to insert post my datas to database from modal with this code.

```php
if (isset($_POST['user_tambah'])) {
    $mitra = $_POST['mitra_input'];
    $username = $_POST['username_input'];
    $password = $_POST['password_input'];
    $privilege = $_POST['privilege_input'];
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO user (name,username, password, privilege) values (? ,?, ?,?)";
    $stmt2 = $connection->prepare($query2);
    $stmt2->bind_param("sssi", $mitra, $username, $password, $privilege);
    $stmt2->execute();

    if ($stmt2->affected_rows) {
        echo "Deleted ".$stmt->affected_rows." rows";
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Berhasil menambah user</div>
        <?php
        header("Location: user.php");
        } else {
        echo "No rows matched the criteria.";
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Gagal menambah user</div>
        <?php
    }
    $stmt2->close();
}
```

from this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="plusModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tambah User</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" action="" id="insert-user-form" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Mitra</label>
                        <input name="mitra_input" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Nama perusahaan" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail1">Username</label>
                        <input name="username_input" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Username untuk masuk" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input name="password_input" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password untuk masuk" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formControlSelect1">Privilege</label>
                        <select name="privilege_input" class="form-control" id="formControlSelect1">
                            <option value="2">User</option>
                            <option value="1">Admin</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="user_tambah" form="insert-user-form">Tambah</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but the if I click the button it do nothing. it don't even have the error. I tried the same way to delete with modal too and it works well, but if I tried it to insert like this it won't click. please help if there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not submit buttons in form scope.
Try this html markup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="plusModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tambah User</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" action="" id="insert-user-form" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Mitra</label>
                        <input name="mitra_input" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Nama perusahaan" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail1">Username</label>
                        <input name="username_input" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Username untuk masuk" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input name="password_input" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password untuk masuk" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="formControlSelect1">Privilege</label>
                        <select name="privilege_input" class="form-control" id="formControlSelect1">
                            <option value="2">User</option>
                            <option value="1">Admin</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="user_tambah" form="insert-user-form">Tambah</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The submit button has `form="insert-user-form"` (which is the forms id) so it should still submit the form.

Comment: I also remove the form="" I don't know why but it works. thanks